# How ca I get Python ArgParse to stop overwritting positional arguments in child parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am attempting to get my script working, but argparse keeps overwriting my positional arguments from the parent parser. How can I get argparse to honor the parent's value for these? It does keep values from optional args.

Here is a very simplified version of what I need. If you run this, you will see that the args are overwritten.

## testargs.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import sys

def main():
    preparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    preparser.add_argument('first',
                        nargs='?')

    preparser.add_argument('outfile',
                        nargs='?',
                        type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding='utf-8'),
                        default=sys.stdout,
                        help='Output file')

    preparser.add_argument(
        '--do-something','-d',
        action='store_true')
    # Parse args with preparser, and find config file
    args, remaining_argv = preparser.parse_known_args()
    print(args)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        parents=[preparser],
        description=__doc__)

    parser.add_argument(
        '--clear-screen', '-c',
        action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args(args=remaining_argv,namespace=args )
    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And call it with `testargs.py something /tmp/test.txt -d -c`

You will see it keeps the `-d` but drops both the positional args and reverts them to defaults.

**EDIT**: see additional comments in the accepted answer for some caveats.

Comment: Why can't you just parse all the args at once? Why do you need the preparser ones first?

Comment: just parsing the original options again with `parser.parse_args()` would work wouldn't it?

Comment: rerunning `parser.parse_args()` does nothing.

Comment: I meant replacing `args = parser.parse_args(args=remaining_argv, namespace=args)` with simply `args = parser.parse_args()` so that it will re-parse the arguments that were already figured out.

Comment: I have to have it setup like this because in the real script some of the args have got to be read early then I pull in setting from defaults then a config file, based on the early args, then lastly some options are overwritten by the passed in args. I just tried to keep this example as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes normally that would work, however, when the script is called I have to separate the args out, and get at the ones in the parent first (read my above comment), this then leaves the remainder of arguments as unknown to the parent, which is why I am passing in the `remaining_argv` to pick them up, perhaps my understanding of this is lacking a bit, is there another way?

Comment: Okay, I apparently have had it wrong all along. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen is correct, it looks like I can just call `args = parser.parse_args()` and it will keep everything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: However that doesn't stop it from opening up the files a second time, although the work around may solve your problem it isn't the proper answer to this question... I wonder if you would just need to not specify `preparser` as the parent of `parser` and keep everything else, then it wouldn't try to re-parse the arguments that were already dealt with in `preparser`.

Comment: You are correct @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, it does in fact open the file twice. I do have `preparser` as the parent of `parser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `parents=[preparser]` it means that `parser` is an extension of `preparser`, and will parse all arguments relevent to `preparser` which it is never given.

Lets say the `preparser` only has one positional argument `first` and the `parser` only has one positional argument `second`, when you make parser a child of preparser it expects **both** arguments:

```
import argparse

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser1.add_argument("first")

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parser1])
parser2.add_argument("second")
args2 = parser2.parse_args(["arg1","arg2"])
assert args2.first == "arg1" and args2.second == "arg2"
```

However passing only the remaining arguments that are left over from `parser1` would just be `['second']` which is not the correct arguments to `parser2`:

```
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser1.add_argument("first")
args1, remaining_args = parser1.parse_known_args(["arg1","arg2"])

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parser1])
parser2.add_argument("second")

>>> args1
Namespace(first='arg1')
>>> remaining_args
['arg2']
>>> parser2.parse_args(remaining_args)
usage: test.py [-h] first second
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: second
```

To only process the arguments that were not handled by the first pass, do not specify it as the parent to the second parser:

```
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser1.add_argument("first")
args1, remaining_args = parser1.parse_known_args(["arg1","arg2"])

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser() #parents=[parser1]) #NO PARENT!
parser2.add_argument("second")
args2 = parser2.parse_args(remaining_args,args1)

assert args2.first == "arg1" and args2.second == "arg2"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I removed the parent reference, and passed in the namespace. Now it is working like I intended it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just a a note to anyone interested. When doing it this way, I lose the help output from the first parser, which means that my positinoal args did not show up in output. So this really makes it a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 positionals are `nargs='?'`.  A positional like that is always 'seen', since an empty list matches that `nargs`.

First time through 'text.txt' matches with `first` and is put in the Namespace.  Second time through there isn't any string to match, so the default is used - same as if you had not given that string the first time.

If I change `first` to have the default `nargs`, I get

```
error: the following arguments are required: first
```

from the 2nd parser. Even though there's a value in the Namespace it still tries to get a value from the `argv`. (it's like a default, but not quite).

Defaults for positionals with `nargs='?'` (or `*`) are tricky.  They are optional, but not in quite the same way as `optionals`.  The positional Actions are still called, but with a empty list of values.

I don't think the `parents` feature does anything for you.  `preparser` already handles that set of arguments; there's no need to handle them again in `parser`, especially since all the relevant argument strings have been stripped out.

Another option is to leave the parents in, but use the default `sys.argv[1:]` in the 2nd parser. (but beware of side effects like opening files)

```
args = parser.parse_args(namespace=args )
```

A third option is to parse the arguments independently and merge them with a dictionary `update`.

```
 adict = vars(preparse_args)
 adict.update(vars(parser_args))
 # taking some care in who overrides who
```

For more details look in `argparse.py` file at `ArgumentParser._get_values`, specifically the `not arg_strings` cases.

A note about the `FileType`.  That type works nicely for small scripts where you will use the files right away and exit.  It isn't so good on large programs where you might want to close the file after use (close `stdout`???), or use files in a `with` context.

---

edit - note on `parents`

`add_argument` creates an `Action` object, and adds it to the parser's list of actions.  `parse_args` basically matches input strings with these actions.

`parents` just copies those Action objects (by reference) from parent to child.  To the child parser it is just as though the actions were created with `add_argument` directly.

`parents` is most useful when you are importing a parser and don't have direct access to its definition.  If you are defining both parent and child, then `parents` just saves you some typing/cut-n-paste.

This and other SO questions (mostly triggered the by-reference copy) show that the developers did not intend you to use both the parent and child to do parsing.  It can be done, but there are glitches that the they did not consider.

===================

I can imagine defining a custom `Action` class that would 'behave' in a situation like this.  It might, for example, check the namespace for some not default value before adding its own (possibly default) value.

Consider, for example if I changed the `action` of `first` to 'append':

```
preparser.add_argument('first', action='append', nargs='?')
```

The result is:

```
1840:~/mypy$ python3 stack37147683.py /tmp/test.txt -d -c
Namespace(do_something=True, first=['/tmp/test.txt'], outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)

Namespace(clear_screen=True, do_something=True, first=['/tmp/test.txt', None], outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

From the first parser, `first=['/tmp/test.txt']`; from the second, `first=['/tmp/test.txt', None]`.

Because of the `append`, the item from the first is preserved, and a new default has been added by the second parser.

Comment: "I don't think the `parents` feature does anything for you ... relevant argument strings have been stripped out." If the `parents` feature was not used it correctly only parses the arguments that were not already handled in the previous pass.  Unless my answer is way off I think using the `parents` feature at all is the root of the problem.

Comment: The OP would have this problem regardless of how 'first' was added to the 2nd parser.